# how to change paper size in Ubuntu Chrome

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, printing

I use Chrome version 79.0.3945.88 in Ubuntu (can't update) and the paper size options for the print are the following:
[image]

I need to print on 4x6in index cards, is there a way to customize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try via CUPS administration:  http://localhost:631/

You should be able to get anything your printer supports there.